# Showing an Error in the code(d.fc is not a function)

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8

**IMPORTS:**

```js
var geometry = /* color: #98ff00 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[73.85016678395664, 14.304113379426035],
      [73.85016583974448, 14.048667693939866],
      [74.0477686190103, 14.155139129529527]]]),
    point1 = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Point([73.91532897949219, 14.20980182205916]),
    point2 = /* color: #98ff00 */ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(
    [[73.9105224609375, 14.169860112219006],
     [73.87619018554688, 14.186503346854852],
     [73.87550354003906, 14.233097898500935],
     [73.93730163574219, 14.199817054773131],
     [73.95378112792969, 14.181177644664091],
     [73.88717651367188, 14.155213055929545],
     [73.92906188964844, 14.141230893912757],
     [73.94691467285156, 14.155878851710582],
     [73.97300720214844, 14.161205147702967],
     [73.98399353027344, 14.165865554216062],
     [73.9764404296875, 14.197820048470204]]);
```

**CODE:**

```js
var image = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_TOA").filterBounds(geometry)
.filterDate('2013-01-01', '2013-04-14');

var addNDWI = function(image) {
var ndwi = image.normalizedDifference(['B3', 'B6']).rename('NDWI');
return image.addBands(ndwi);
};
var image1 = image.map(addNDWI);

var fg_points = 
[ee.Feature(geometry),ee.Feature(point1),ee.Feature(point2)];
Map.addLayer(ee.Feature(geometry), {}, "geometry");
Map.addLayer(ee.Feature(point1), {}, "point1");
Map.addLayer(ee.Feature(point2), {}, "point2");


var mapfunc = function(feat) {
var geom = feat.geometry()
var addProp = function(img, f) {
var newf = ee.Feature(f)
var date = img.date().format()
var value = img.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.first(), geom, 30).get('NDWI')
return ee.Feature(ee.Algorithms.If(value,
                                   newf.set(date, ee.String(value)),
                                   newf.set(date, ee.String('No data'))))
}
var newfeat = ee.Feature(image1.iterate(addProp, feat))
return newfeat
};


var newft = fg_points.map(mapfunc);

Export.table.toDrive(newft,
"export_Points",
"export_Points",
"export_Points");
```

Can someone explain where I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement:

```js
var newft = fg_points.map(mapfunc);
```

is mapping a function over a JavaScript list of features (`fg_points`) which results in `newft` being a list as well. You are then passing the list to `Export.table.toDrive()`, but a list is not a valid input parameter for the method. You need to convert it to a collection first:

```js
var newft = ee.FeatureCollection(fg_points.map(mapfunc));
```